# How to generate new nested array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Imagine we have an array with 3 arrays inside and each element is a 7-element-array. (like arr[3][7])
I want to transfer these elements to a new array like arr2[3][1][7]. I tried foreach method and it copies the last nested array to all new elements.

```
    var c3 = new Array(players).fill(new Array(1).fill(new Array(7)))
    // console.log(c2)
    // c2= [
        // [x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7],
        // [y1, y2, y3, y4, y5, y6, y7],
        // [z1, z2, z3, z4, z5, z6, z7]]


    c2.forEach(function (val, ind) {
        c3[ind][0] = c2[ind]
    })

    // it supposed to return c3:
        // [
        // [[x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7]],
        // [[y1, y2, y3, y4, y5, y6, y7]],
        // [[z1, z2, z3, z4, z5, z6, z7]]]

    // But it returns:
        // [
        // [[z1, z2, z3, z4, z5, z6, z7]],
        // [[z1, z2, z3, z4, z5, z6, z7]],
        // [[z1, z2, z3, z4, z5, z6, z7]]]
```

Comment: Seem like you keep references. Try adding `c2.slice()` to make copy of array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this ?

```js
const data = [
  ['x1', 'x2', 'x3', 'x4', 'x5', 'x6', 'x7'],
  ['y1', 'y2', 'y3', 'y4', 'y5', 'y6', 'y7'],
  ['z1', 'z2', 'z3', 'z4', 'z5', 'z6', 'z7'],
];

const res = data.map(v => [v]);

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

I  hope this helps

```js
function flatten(array){
           const res = [];    
           for(let i = 0; i< array.length; i++){
               if(Array.isArray(array[i])){
                   const flat = flatten(array[i])
                   for(let j = 0; j < flat.length; j++){
                       res.push(flat[j])
                   }
               }else{
                   res.push(array[i])
               }
           }
           return res
       }
       
       console.log(flatten( [ [1], [[2],[3]], [[[[4]]]]] )) 

output //  [1, 2, 3, 4]
```